# Where can I get a list of blockchain network?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, blockchain-fork

Ethereum is just one network out of many?

Where can I get a list of blockchain networks (ethereum, bitcoin, ripple, Stellar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blockchains are often categorized by the consensus algorithm they use, therefore it is worth taking a look at [Blockchain Consensus Encyclopedia](https://tokens-economy.gitbook.io/consensus). The site contains numerous blockchain projects that are listed in each consensus algorithm's "Used in" section.

You can get a broad idea from this picture:

[image: summary]

- PoW chains:

  - Bitcoin
  - Litecoin
  - Ethereum
- PoS chains:

  - Ethereum 2
  - Tezos
- PoH chains:

  - Solana
- DAGs:

  - Iota

...

If you are looking for Ethereum compatible chains only, visit https://chainlist.org/

Answer (score 1):

The best sources I know that covers all blockchain would be cryptocurrency prices websites like coingecko.
Most EVM compatible chains can be found [here](https://chainlist.org/)